# how it is/was possible that

Tags: grammaticality

**Sentences:**

1. John and I aren't friends anymore. He was my friend, but then he stole my wallet. I wonder how it **is** possible that he **did** that to me.
2. John and I aren't friends anymore. He was my friend, but then he stole my wallet. I wonder how it **was** possible that he **did** that to me.

**Question:**

Do the bolded tenses work in the above two sentences? Thanks.

Comment: Both 'was' and 'is' work (emphasising history or an unresolved problem, respectively), but I'd prefer '... that he could do that to me'.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Edwin Ashworth. How about the simple past "did"? Does it work in the two versions from the point of view of grammar? Thanks.

Comment: Grammar, according to Orwell, is very important but not as important as not sounding unnatural or being unclear / misleading. Here, 'I wonder how it is possible that he did that to me' would default in meaning to 'He must be a magician', a statement about physical rather than behavioural impossibility (and an awkward-sounding one; 'I wonder how he managed to do that to me!' (eg reset my watch while it never seemed to leave my pocket) sounds more natural).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.